# 400 Bad Request in MVC C# Web App but not Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.text.json

I have the following method that I've been working on for hours now and am not able to `PUT` my updates to an external `Ellucian Ethos API`.

```
public async Task<string> UpdatePersonH11()
{
    var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync("TokenApi", "value");
    var guid = await GetPersonGUID(token);
    Uri personsURI = new Uri(string.Format("https://URLtoAPI" + guid));

    H11Model h11Data = new H11Model
    {
        h11 = new h11
        {
            extendedPersonUser2 = "2021/FA",
            extendedPersonUser3 = "OUT",
            extendedPersonUser4 = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() 
        }
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = personsURI;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v12+json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
      
        var responseString = "";
        var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(h11Data);

        **using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(personsURI, content))** Debugger stops here and gives me a 400 Bad Request
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                   
            }
            else
            {
                log.Debug("Error in response." + response);
                return "";
            }
            return responseString;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `json` that Json is serializing for the variable `content` to send through `PutAsJsonAsync`.

```
{
    "h11":  
    {
        "extendedPersonUser2":"2021/FA",
        "extendedPersonUser3":"OUT",
        "extendedPersonUser4":"8/5/2021",
    }
}
```

H11 Model

```
public class H11Model
{        
    [JsonProperty("h11")]
    public h11 h11 { get; set; }
}

public class h11
{
    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser2")]
    public string extendedPersonUser2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser3")]
    public string extendedPersonUser3 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser4")]
    public string extendedPersonUser4 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser5")]
    public string extendedPersonUser5 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser6")]
    public string extendedPersonUser6 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser7")]
    public string extendedPersonUser7 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser8")]
    public string extendedPersonUser8 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser9")]
    public string extendedPersonUser9 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("extendedPersonUser10")]
    public string extendedPersonUser10 { get; set; }
}
```

I've read that `PutAsJsonAsync` does not need the content serialized first, but when I comment out `var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(h11Data);` I get a `406 Not Acceptable` error, that leads me to believe that I do need to serialize the content first.

This is the request message I get back from the debugger:

```
{
    Method: PUT, 
    RequestUri: 'API URI', 
    Version: 1.1, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.ObjectContent`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=token]],
    Headers:
    {
        Authorization: Bearer 'token is here'
        Accept: application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v12+json
        Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
        Content-Length: 293
    }
}
```

This is the response message:

```
{
    StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
        Connection: keep-alive
        pragma: no-cache
        hedtech-ethos-integration-application-id: GUID
        hedtech-ethos-integration-application-name: Colleague
        vary: origin
        access-control-expose-headers: x-max-page-size,x-media-type,x-total-count,x-content-restricted,hedtech-ethos-integration-application-id,hedtech-ethos-integration-application-name,hedtech-ethos-integration-proxy-generated
        Cache-Control: no-cache
        Date: Fri, 06 Aug 2021 13:41:56 GMT
        Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
        Content-Length: 447
        Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
        Expires: -1
    }
}
```

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. I haven't used APIs this way before, so this is new territory for me and I am stumped on this.

EDIT: Final code (snippet) that works:

```
H11Model h11Data = new H11Model
        {
            h11 = new h11
            {
                extendedPersonUser5 = "OUT", // fall term
                extendedPersonUser6 = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
            }
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = personsURI;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.hedtech.integration.v12+json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");                                       

            var responseString = "";
            //var content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(h11Data);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(personsURI, h11Data))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    catch (NotSupportedException ex) // When content type is not valid
                    {
                        log.Debug("The content type is not supported.", ex);
                    }
                    catch (JsonException ex) // Invalid JSON
                    {
                        log.Debug("Invalid JSON.", ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Debug("Error in response." + response);
                    return "";
                }
                return responseString;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried passing h11Data without serialize that?  Pass directly.

Comment: Try using `client.PutAsync()` instead of `client.PutAsJsonAsync()`.

Comment: Error 400 could be thrown with many reasons, one of the common reasons is because of **NOT VALID** data you pass, are you sure your model is valid?

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron If I try to pass h11Data without serializing, I get a 406 Not Acceptable error. That makes me think I need to serialize the data since it is an MVC model, not json. Thanks

Comment: @HassanMonjezi when I update to `client.PutAsync` I get a 406 Not Acceptable error.
I did this: `var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(h11Data);` 
`var content = new StringContent(jsonString);`
 `using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(personsURI.ToString(), content))` and the content comes back as bytes, not json. I'm not sure if I am using that correctly.

Comment: @AbhayDesai I updated the post to show the response message I'm getting back. It's a 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: Please verify HTTP headers in request when receive 406 Not Acceptable error, especially check values of Accept, Accept-Encoding. It looks like that in Postman you have different values.

_"I get a 406 Not Acceptable error. That makes me think I need to serialize the data since it is an MVC model, not json."_ No, JSON is Ok, headers are wrong. See [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service does not override the meaning of the HTTP codes and uses them as described in RFC then

[406 Not Acceptable](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.6)

> The 406 (Not Acceptable) status code indicates that the target resource does not have a current representation that would be acceptable to the user agent, according to the proactive negotiation header fields received in the request ([Section 5.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-5.3)), and the server is unwilling to supply a default representation.

Simply put, the value of `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Accept-Charset` or `Accept-Language` HTTP header is invalid or not defined as service expects.

In the described case, there are at least two such headers set through `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` collection. Their values need to be compared with the service documentation.  And it is important to note that in the general case the `Accept-Encoding` header should be set via [`HttpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.automaticdecompression) property instead of `DefaultRequestHeaders` collection, otherwise it will be ignored.

[400 Bad Request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1)

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

For example, service expects `{ "h11": { "extendedPersonUser2": ...` JSON object; but instead of it, service receives `"{ \"h11\": { \"extendedPersonUser2\": ...` and cannot deserialize it.

As it was already mentioned in comments, there is a difference between [`PutAsJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.putasjsonasync) extension method and [`HttpClient.PutAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.putasync) method with [`StringContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent). The first one sends a PUT request to the specified Uri containing the value serialized as JSON in the request body. The `PutAsync` method sends raw content as it is defined by content argument.

So, the code from example

```
   string content = JsonSerializer.Serialize(h11Data);
   ... = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(personsURI, content);
```

uses `PutAsJsonAsync` and sends JSON string additionally serialized to JSON. As result service receives the following content `"{ \"h11\": { \"extendedPersonUser2\": ...`.

Usually, when `PutAsJsonAsync` extension method is used, the additional JSON serialization is not needed. Content object can be passed directly to `PutAsJsonAsync` extension method.

```
   ... = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(personsURI, h11Data);
```

In such case the request will be sent as `{ "h11": { "extendedPersonUser2": ...`.

There are multiple `PutAsJsonAsync` extension method overloads that also accept `JsonSerializerOptions` to customize JSON serialization. And it's important to note that `PutAsJsonAsync` internally use `HttpClient.PutAsync` method with `StringContent` to send the request.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that to me. I commented out `.Serialize` and threw `h11Data` in the `.PutasJsonAsync` request and it seemed to work this time.  Thanks so much!!!!!